# Adding contents of arrayList to a JTextPane document

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextpane

In my Java program I'm trying to add data from an `ArrayList` to a `JTextPane` document. I've tried the following wrapped in a for loop without success:

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),colorList[j] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("bold"));
```

I've been looking through the Java Docs for an answer but it's incredibly overwhelming. How I can put information from an `ArrayList`into a `JTextPane` document?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I updated my post to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of iterating over elements of an `ArrayList` and inserting them to a `JTextPane`:

```
public class Texting extends JFrame {

    Texting() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("AAAAAAA");
        list.add(" ");
        list.add("BBBB");

        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        Document doc = pane.getDocument();
        for (String s : list)
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s, null);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        add(pane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Texting();
    }
}
```